# contenteditable div is showing raw html instead of rendered html

Tags: javascript, html

When I replace the user selection in a `contenteditable` div using this function below, then the "new" HTML appears as text (raw HTML) instead of rendered HTML in the div.

In other words, the `<h2>` tag is being inserted as `<h2>`, so the display is `<h2>` instead of a "html heading line".

What am I doing wrong?

```js
function replaceWYS() {
  var sel, range;
  if (window.getSelection) {
    sel = window.getSelection();

    selT = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
    replacementText = "<h2>" + selT + "</h2>";

    if (sel.rangeCount) {
      range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
      range.deleteContents();
      range.insertNode(document.createTextNode(replacementText));
    }
  } else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
    range = document.selection.createRange();
    range.text = replacementText;
  }

}
```

```html
<div id="wys" contenteditable>
  This is line<br><br> This line should be heading after replacement
  <br><br> Select it and click the replace button
</div>
<p><button onclick="replaceWYS(); return false;"> Replace now </button></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.createTextNode` renders your HTML as text (if you log it you get `"<h2>...</h2>"` instead of `<h2>...</h2>`). You can create an HTML element manually.

```js
function replaceWYS() {
  var sel, range;
  if (window.getSelection) {
    sel = window.getSelection();

    selT = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
    const h = document.createElement("h2");
    h.innerText = selT;

    if (sel.rangeCount) {
      range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
      range.deleteContents();
      range.insertNode(h);
    }
  } else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
    range = document.selection.createRange();
    range.text = replacementText;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="wys" contenteditable>
  This is line<br><br> This line should be heading after replacement
  <br><br> Select it and click the replace button
</div>
<p><button onclick="replaceWYS(); return false;"> Replace now </button></p>
```

Comment: This is doing something even more weird. Suppose original text was this: "This is Replacement Line<br><br>more..." Then it gets replaced to this: "[object HTMLHeadingElement]<br><br>more..."

Comment: @John, huh, it's not happening for me. Could you add a link to a screencast?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I only copied the first part of your editted code into my js code. My mistake, so sorry. This is working fine. I'm accepting the answer. One more help please. How do I insert a <a href="url"> some text </a> tag using this code? Thanks

Comment: @John great! Could you provide some more context on how you're going to convert text to a link? What data is the user going to provide?